# Run time data handling in Adaptive card

Tags: android, ios

I have some data in a dictionary, I want to create Adaptive using this data. Layout for Adaptive card is fixed, I just want to replace data based on my current state. 
Is it supported?

Answer (score 0):

You can have your Adaptive card created using custom JSON as [Documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/sdk/rendering-cards/android/render-a-card#create-adaptive-card-object-instance-from-json-text) here.

You can also refer to [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/AdaptiveCards) for working sample app hosted at github.

Hope this helps.